# How to subscribe LinkedIn webhook events?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, webhooks

I am trying to subscribe LinkedIn Organization Social Action Notifications using
`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{developer application ID},user:urn:li:user:{member ID},entity:urn:li:organization:{organization ID},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)`
api.

I have passed all the necessary fields.But I am receiving the below error.

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/user]"
}
```

How to resolve this issue?